# Помогите разобраться с учебным заданием в си

Tags: c

Есть учебное задание на бросание костей (бросание 6000 раз и вывод "таблицы") в принципе элементарное. Понимаю как всё работает, но не получается ответ. 
вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
  int face, roll, frequency1 = 0, frequency2 = 0, frequency3 = 0, frequency4 = 0, frequency5 = 0, frequency6 = 0;

  for (roll = 1; roll <= 6000; roll++) // прокручивание 6000 раз 
    face = 1 + rand() % 6; // Добавление смещения и использование функции rand cо сдвигом масштабирования на 6

  switch (face) 
  {
    case 1:
      ++frequency1;  // добавление в переменную 1
      break;         // конец цикла
    case 2:
      ++frequency2;
      break;     
    case 3:
      ++frequency3;
      break;     
    case 4:
      ++frequency4;
      break;     
    case 5:
      ++frequency5;
      break;     
    case 6:
      ++frequency6;
      break;      
  }

  printf("%s%13s\n", "Face", "Frequency");
  printf("1%13d\n", frequency1);
  printf("1%13d\n", frequency2);
  printf("1%13d\n", frequency3);
  printf("1%13d\n", frequency4);
  printf("1%13d\n", frequency5);
  printf("1%13d\n", frequency6);

  return 0;
}
```

Получаю при выходе:

```
Face    Frequency
1            0
1            0
1            0
1            0
1            1
1            0
```

Можете указать на мою ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swith-case в блок фора фозьми. У тебя без тела только face = 1 + rand() % 6; 6000 раз выполняется.

Comment: точно, спасибо большое) невнимательность блин((

Comment: А что, с понятием "массив" автор вопроса не знаком?